# Java Swing - Focus Listener

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, focuslistener

I have a custom Focus Listener for my java program and whenever I start the program its automatically focused in my first JTextField when it shouldn't be focused at all. I also cant un-focus off the JTextField without focusing on the other bottom JTextField and visa versa. It was working fine until I started using my custom Focus Listener.

[image: program]

Heres my Focus Listener:

```java
public class FocusListener implements java.awt.event.FocusListener
{
    private final JTextField textField;
    private final String text;

    public FocusListener(JTextField textField, String text)
    {
        this.textField = textField;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        if (textField.getText().equals(text))
        {
            textField.setText("");
            textField.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        if (textField.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            textField.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
            textField.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: then what _should_ be focused initially? most users would expect that they can start typing right away .. If you really insist, you might try a custom focusTraversalPolicy and override getInitialComponent to return null. Anyway, [mcve] required (to demonstrate the _It was working fine until I started using my custom Focus Listener_)

Comment: Alright, Using a custom focusTraversalPolicy and overriding getInitialComponent works fine. But how do I make it so the user can click any where else in the window to unfocus the text field?

Comment: _user can click any where else in the window to unfocus the text field?_ why?

Comment: Its annoying having the cursor constantly flashing every few seconds once you have inputed everything needed...

Comment: hmm .. how do you detect the _everything needed_? when you do, you can disable the textField or make it not editable. Anyway, this feels like xy-problem and some broken UX (can't know without seeing an example that you insist on not showing ;) - good luck!

Comment: *how do I make it so the user can click any where else in the window to unfocus the text field?* - this is the default behaviour. If it doesn't work then your custom FocusTraversalPolicy is likely causing a problem.